# Automating Safari Page on iOS

Tags: java, ios, cucumber

[A picture of the page I'm trying to automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EbqY.png)

Attempting to automate the gmail sign in page on iOS simulator. I am able to automate entering my email and password just fine, but run into some troubles at the page right after it. The following code is used to tap on the 'I am not interested' link shown in the image:

```
 waitForPageToLoad(2000);
 driver.findElement(By.className("oo")).click();
```

Alternative selector strategy I used were by xpath, id, and name. I found these using Appium inspector:

```
waitForPageToLoad(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="I am not interested"]")).click();
```

However both strategies end up with the same result: The server is unable to tap on the element. The tests then time out (504 Gateway Time-out).

Appium server logs reveal a possible memory leak? Here is the line of interest:

```
(node:77457) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```